# Is it possible to declare a method for each parameter in a pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

For example:

```
template<class... keys>
struct{
    { virtual keys* getContents(foo* Foo) const = 0 }...;
}
```

or:

```
template<class... keys>
struct{
    virtual bar* getBar( keys* Foo )... const = 0;
}
```

Or anything with similar effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function or a method cannot return a parameter pack.

A function can return a `std::tuple`, though:

```
template<class... keys>
struct something {
    virtual std::tuple<keys...> getContents(foo* Foo) const = 0;
}
```

You could also specialize this template for a single type, and return the type instead of a one-element tuple; and specialize it for an empty parameter pack, and return a `void`.

EDIT:

You clarified your question. You were trying to do something different, and your initial explanation was understandably somewhat off the mark.

You can accomplish what you're looking, but it's a little bit more complicated, and requires recursive templates and specialization, but looks like this is what you want.

```
class bar;

template<typename ...Keys> struct getcontents_base;

template<>
struct getcontents_base<> {
};

template<typename firstKey, typename ...remainingKeys>
struct getcontents_base<firstKey, remainingKeys...>
    : getcontents_base<remainingKeys...> {

    virtual bar *getBar(firstKey *foo) const=0;
};

struct getcontents : public getcontents_base<int, char> {

    bar *getBar(int *) const override {}
    bar *getBar(char *) const override {}
};

struct notgetcontents : public getcontents_base<int, char> {};

void foo()
{
    struct getcontents c; // This will compile fine.

    struct notgetcontents c2; // This will result in a compilation error
                              // because the virtual methods have not
                              // been defined.
}
```

Comment: What I really want to do, is require derived classes to implement gettors for each "key" they advertize to the base class.

If I specialize them manually, that would mean re-writing the base class any time any derived class was changed.

Is there a way to get one method for each type in the pack?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer, in response to your clarification.

Comment: Wow. Did you ever update that answer. That does seem to be what I am looking for.

Is this interpretation correct - every time 'getcontents_base' is specialized, the compiler defines one specialization of getBar, than starts over with one less type in the parameter pack?

So by the time its done, each getcontents_base<> in the inheritance graph has 1 version of getBar, accounting for all the types that 'getcontents' passed to it initially?

Comment: That's pretty much how it works. There might be some issues with overload resolution. If so, it might be necessary to define a specialization for a parameter pack with a single parameter, and add "using getcontents_base<remainingKeys...>::getBar;" to the recursive template. It depends upon your application, whether you need to do that or not.